# C#: Multiple Threads Inside Lock Block

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm seeing a very interesting phenomenon, where multiple threads are inside a lock statement. I have the following section of code:

```
private readonly object _overalllock = new object();

public async Task Method()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   lock (_overalllock)
                   {
                      //Section A//
                   }
               }
}
```

Inside the "Section A" block, I started seeing some interesting behavior. On further investigation, I noted that there are multiple threads inside this area. I would've thought that all the threads would be blocked at the lock statement, and only start executing when the lock object becomes free?

Please also note that the above section of code can be called from a thread other than the main thread. What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: When is _overalllock  new'd?  Are they in separate instantiations of the class?

Comment: Taking a lock inside a Task defeats its purpose. *What* do you want to achieve and why do you think you need a lock for this? If you have a pub/sub scenario, why not use a BlockingQueue or an ActionBlock?

Answer (score 2):

The lock object `_overalllock` is an instance-level field. If you have multiple instances of the class then the lock is only effective on instance level. In order for blocking access for all threads, no matter which instance they operate on, you need to make the lock object static:

```
private static readonly object _overalllock = new object();
```

For details on the `lock` statement, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: Also you can introduce your own `Singleton` and lock over it in your app.